# JavaScript puts # in URL, new page opens halfway

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working on [this website](http://www.florayuda.nl) to get it responsive, which is a static HTML website which uses some JavaScript to load `index.html` on every page.

The problem is that the JavaScript code puts a `#` before every link. When you click a link somewhere halfway a page, it will open the new page also somewhere halfway (same scroll position as the link was on the old page).

How can I make the new page always open at the top of the page?

The JavaScript file contains the following script (which is gibberish to me...)

```
var ScriptJS = true;
var lastLocation = document.location.href;

$(document).ready(function () {
if (!$('#ajax').length) { // Check if index.html was loaded. If not, navigate to index.html and load the hash part with ajax.
    document.location = document.location.href.substring(0, 
document.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) +
        "#" + 
document.location.href.substr(document.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 }

if (window.location.hash) // Check if the page is being loaded with a '#'. Load the file.
    $('#ajax').load(window.location.hash.substr(1));
});

$(document).on("click", "a:not(.regular)", function (e) {
var url = this.href;
if (url.indexOf("https") != -1 || url.indexOf('.html') == -1) // External link or picture
    return;

e.preventDefault();

$('#ajax').load(url, function () {
    var pagename = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    lastLocation = document.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, "") 
+ '#' + pagename;
    document.location.href = '#' + pagename;
});
});

window.onpopstate = function (event) {
if (lastLocation != document.location.href)
    location.reload();
else
    return;
};
```

Comment: `document.location.href = '#' + pagename;` looks like your culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Your script uses AJAX to fetch a new page and replace the contents of the current page with the loaded content.

The '#pagename` is probably just there for making the browser's back button work. You could comment that out if you don't want it, but you'll have the same behavior.

What you want to do is to set `document.body.scrollTop = 0;` after the  `document.location.href = ...` line.

Comment: Thanks for your respons David (and Sesamechicken as well of course), this seems to work fine!

Comment: Hmmm this doesn't seem to work in FireFox and IE11... it does work on Chrome, Edge, Android and Iphone. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Bob: The scroll appears to occur in different containers depending on browser. Since you're using jQuery `$('html, body').scrollTop(0)` should cater to both.

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks again for your quick respons, now it works in FF and IE as well :-)